# My Modal is not working in Bootstrap, can't see what is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code. I can't see why it's not working maybe it's an issue with javascript imports?

Thanks guys.

```
        <link href="Bootstrap,%20from%20Twitter_files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <div class="container">  
    <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
    <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">  
    <div class="modal-header">  
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
    <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>  
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-body">  
    <h4>Text in a modal</h4>  
    <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-footer">  
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
    </div>  
    </div>  
    <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a></p>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine with me http://jsfiddle.net/SpYNe/133/

```
<div class="container">  
<h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
<div id="example" class="modal hide fade">  
<div class="modal-header">  
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
<h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>  
</div>  
<div class="modal-body">  
<h4>Text in a modal</h4>  
<p>You can add some text here.</p>                
</div>  
<div class="modal-footer">  
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
</div>  
</div>  
<p><a data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-    large">Launch demo modal</a></p>  
</div>
```

Maybe there is something wrong with your js path. You should check that

Comment: It works to display but the close button doesn't appear to work in your fiddle.

Comment: Huh, so it does. This is strange,